# Bootstrap accordion not opening

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this issue and nothing seems to be working. The collapsible tab is open but will not switch to the other 2 tabs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfolio</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Your Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Portfoilio</title>
</head>
<body>

<section class="tabs">
    <img src="images/sean.jpg">

    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jrate/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/about.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just a small snippit from my website and I can link to the whole project if you need more information.

Comment: The snippet throws an error. Start by fixing that. A URL ending in `.css` is a stylesheet, not a script.

Comment: I deleted the script link with the css along with the other lightbox link because I wasn't using them and it still didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `CSS` & `JS`  Files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfolio</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Your Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" />
    <title>Portfoilio</title>
</head>
<body>

<section class="tabs">
    <img src="images/sean.jpg">

    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jrate/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/about.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```